# In Visual studio, what is the difference between 'target framework' and advanced build settings 'language version'?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio (I use 2017 at this moment), you can choose a target framework.

[image: target framework]

But you can also choose language settings in Advanced Build Settings -> Language version:

[image]

I can set the Target framework to 4.7 and the language version to <del>4.</del>7.2
Is that the same as setting the target framework to 4.7.2?
What is the difference?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could set the language version to 4.7.2. Have you opened the drop-down list?

Comment: Yes.
Last week, I did not have the target frameworks 4.7.1 and 4.7.2 installed, but could set the language version to 4.7.1 or 4.7.2 via the drop down.

Comment: Then you dropdown is broken, because it should list ISO-1, ISO-2, C#3, C#4, C#5, C#6, and C#'s 7.0 - 7.3, plus a few "indirect" options such as "C# latest major version (default)" that you're showing above.

Comment: Target framework matters most to your user, he's got to have at least that version installed on his machine.  Language version matters most to you, it selects what kind of code you can write.  Your user doesn't care about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET framework has a separate version history from the C# language. The framework defines what classes exist in the class library, for example.

The C# language version defines what syntax is available to you. For example in version two the language got *generics*, in 3.0 we got *Linq*, and so on. There is no language version 4.7.2, that is the version name of a recent .NET framework. If you choose from the language version dropdown you should be able to see e.g. 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 (latest).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history

Common framework versions for the so called "full" .NET framework are

4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

You could say the language version only applies at compile time. The target framework decides what framework will be required by the *consumer* of your application. If you target framework 4.6 then consumers will need to have 
at least that framework.

Note that concepts such as .NET core/standard confuse the framework choice somewhat, but I think that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I can use language features from 4.7.3, and still target 4.7.0? And my customers would only need to have 4.7.0 installed?

Comment: If you mean C# version 7.3 (not 4.7.3. which doesn't exist) then yes - you can use C#7.3 features, for example "readonly struct", and target an older .net framework, and your customers need only worry about the framework you targeted, not which language version you used.

Comment: Yes, I meant 7.3
I think my confusion comes from the fact that the framework versions and language version seem to differ only from the 4.x.x. Apparently, there is not a direct link between these numbers.